# AES decryption in Javascrpt

Tags: javascript, aes

I have create an encrypted string using AES in C#,same need to be decrypted from my JS file.can someone please help on this.

encrypted base 64 string : "+9vxE8iW1hYIKziSJn4Y1Q8xb81ZCuc4OINOFrFXN7sFd2PT6kq6SyJI+/SVmhDmz/HfT+Y+vwuDERLdtk1tE1vlbEf0QHm3NeYVeFz9/uYHYtbne6TTF4Aan/Je2M8NLTt31+buagzmugLKnlmcXTydqNbcYxOXcI5cxKzUhh7TmRXv49zXQw8UjUp7+6en" 
Key : "8080808080808080"
IV : "8080808080808080"

rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; 
rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

able to decrypt the value through online sites(https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) but not using JavaScript code.

```
key = "8080808080808080";
iv = "8080808080808080";
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    
  })
 
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Comment: What happens if you just print `decrypted` to the console?  What happens *now*?  "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Parse key and IV as `WordArray` with the Utf8 encoder, i.e. with `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(...)` and pass the `WordArray`s to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` instead of the strings, s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

Comment: @Topaco thanks a lot.. its working :) :)